# Passing index value from for loop to a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple outputs in html. I want to reach them with for loop. 
For example: unitsTotal = 4;

Then I want to have (output1, tag1), (output2, tag2), (output3, tag3), (output4, tag4).

And I don't know how to pass i inside a string. Can someone help me with doing that? Maybe there is a better idea how to make it.

```
for (var i = 1; i < unitsTotal; i += 1) {
        $(':input[name="output"]').val(output1.toFixed(5).toString());
        $('#output').text(tag1);    
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you use variable variables. *"Maybe there is a better idea how to make it."* Use an array and index into it. [Learn about arrays from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Note: `.toFixed` already returns a string, there is no need to call `.toString`.

Comment: it's not very clear what you're asking here? Are you just looking for `$('#output').text("tag" + i);`

Comment: And would that even work with an ID, it's unique, so there's only element with that ID ?

Comment: $(':input[name="output1"]') .... $(':input[name="output2"]') .... $(':input[name="output3"]') That is what I want to get

Comment: Ah. You just have to use string concatenation.